# WEKA: usage of crossValidateModel

Tags: java, weka

I was trying to follow the weka example using Eclipse, which is about decision tree evaluation  and copied from weka page

http://weka.wikispaces.com/Generating+classifier+evaluation+output+manually

```
Classifier cls = new J48();
Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(data);
Random rand = new Random(1);  // using seed = 1
int folds = 10;
eval.crossValidateModel(cls, data, folds, rand);
System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString());
```

However, the Eclipse compiler gives the following message:

> The method crossValidateModel(Classifier, Instances, int, Random,  Object[]) in the type Evaluation is not applicable for the arguments  (Classifier, Instances, int, Random)

I tried different version of weka.jar, but none of theme removes the above error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with MATLAB. Try to pass another empty Object Array to `crossValidateModel`. Something around:

```
eval.crossValidateModel(cls, data, folds, rand, new Object[] { });
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using wrong classes. Include your imports.